# Finding Max & Min for varying lines in a list VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, max, min

I'm having trouble turning my thought process into tangible code and honestly I'm not sure where to start with the code. I have a data set with two applicable columns, for the sake of simplicity we'll say A and B. A contains a list of three initials followed by a number, ex. JFD3, JFD2, JFD6, EUW1, YMG2, YMG3. Column B has a value. I need to find the range of the highest to lowest values for each set of initials, which has me thinking a max - min solution. The list of initials isn't necessarily in order, and there could be one set of initials(with a net variance of 0, which is OK), or up to 8 sets of initials, with the numbers not necessarily being consecutive. I was thinking some sort of Match(Left(3)) but i don't think that would encompass everything.

Any ideas on where to start would be much appreciated. I'll be happy to clarify if theres any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionaries from the Scripting Runtime to do this easily.  Use two of them with the initials as the keys, one holding the minimum values found and the other holding the maximum values found.

Add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Tools->Add reference..., then check the box next to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime") or late bind (see instructions below).  Something like this should do the trick, assumes initials in column 1, values in column 2, no headers:

```
Private Sub MinMax()    
    Dim mins As Dictionary
    Dim maxes As Dictionary
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    Set mins = New Dictionary
    Set maxes = New Dictionary

    Dim row As Long
    For row = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Dim key As Variant
        Dim val As Integer

        key = sheet.Cells(row, 1).Value2
        If Len(key) >= 3 Then
            key = Left$(sheet.Cells(row, 1).Value2, 3)
            val = sheet.Cells(row, 2).Value2

            If Not mins.Exists(key) Then
                mins.Add key, val
            Else
                If mins(key) > val Then mins(key) = val
            End If

            If Not mins.Exists(key) Then
                maxes.Add key, val
            Else
                If maxes(key) < val Then maxes(key) = val
            End If
        End If
    Next row

    For Each key In mins.Keys
        Debug.Print key & ": Min = "; mins(key) & " Max = "; maxes(key)
    Next key
End Sub
```

To use late binding, the code is exactly the same with these exceptions. Instead of declaring mins and maxes as Dictionary, declare them as Object:

```
    Dim mins As Object
    Dim maxes As Object
```

And instead of setting them as New Dictionary, use CreateObject:

```
    Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    Set mins = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set maxes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach. However, I'm having trouble pulling in the object. I used the code line you have in your comment, `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`, but to no avail. I'm getting the error "User Defined type not defined." I am using this code within a bigger macro, without the "Private" label before sub. Would this be the potential cause? I'm not really sure what the "Private" label changes.

Comment: @Swolerosis - If you're using CreateObject, you also need to change the variable declarations to Object.  See the edit.

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfect. Do you by chance know somewhere I could read up on objects and implementation?

Comment: @Swolerosis - Wow, now *that* is the tough question.  The first object models you should get to know are the Office objects and the Scripting Runtime (it winds up in roughly 80-90% of what I code in VBA).  MS documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bstcxhf7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). More generally, the Object Browser is my go-to.  Hit `F2` in your IDE and you see function prototypes, return values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pivot Table. Put your Column A field<sup>*</sup> in the `Row Labels`, then put column B in the Values twice. Change one from `Sum` to `Min`, and the other from `Sum` to `Max`.

<sup>*</sup> Not sure if you need to group by `JFD` for all `JFDx` or by each `JFDx`. If you need them grouped by the 3 initials, make a column C `=left("A1",3)`, then use that in your

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I'm trying to get this into VBA. The project overall looks over a variety of values and items in the data and spits out a report of any issues outside my tolerance for each item.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to this could be:

1. Sort the data in the range A-B by A in alphabetical order. To do this, you can record a macro while doing this action and edit the code to make it dynamically working every time. This is *required* to make the below solution work, *more performing* for many other kinds of similar approaches.
2. Use `While` blocks to run the solution. I let you take the time to build and test a working code, but this is the idea:

   ```
   startSubset = 2 '<-- we start getting the key from row 2
   'build the key to define the subset
   keyStart = 1 
   currentKey = ""
   Do While Not IsNumeric(Right(Left(Range("A" & startSubset),keyStart),1))
       'while the last char of the key is not numeric, let's add it to the key
       currentKey = currentKey & Right(Left(Range("A" & startSubset),keyStart),1)
       keyStart = keyStart + 1
   Loop
   ```

After the above, the key is stored in the variable `currentKey`. It will be `JFD` if the first cell is `JFD213`, etc. Hence, you loop until the end of this subset storing max and min in two variables:

```
    min = 0
    max = 0
    Do While Left(Range("A" & startSubset),Len(currentKey)) = currentKey
        If Range("B" & startSubset) < min Then min = Range("B" & startSubset)
        If Range("B" & startSubset) > max Then max = Range("B" & startSubset)
        startSubset = startSubset + 1
    Loop
```

1. Once this is done, you just need to cast the values into a collection, for example:

   ```
   myObs.Add(currentKey)
   myObs.Add(min)
   myObs.Add(max) '<-- you will get something like myObs = ("DJF", 0, 100)
   ```

Then cast this object into a bigger collection:

```
    allValues.Add(myObs) '<-- at the end you will have something like this:
    'allValues = [("DJF",0,100), ("ABC", 1, 75), ...]
```

and re-set the values to let them continue:

```
    currentKey = ""
    keyStart = 1
```

All the above, should be run in a `While` loop that will break when the data are over.

Please note the above code cannot work standing-alone, but it's rather a possible approach to the problem that you will need to re-work on your data to make it work in real life.